# python start() stop() multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I would like to start multiprocessing with infinite loop in one python file and then in other file would say if process is running by name and stoping it if running. I have played with examples in web, but have not found how to target running multiprocess by name.

When I created process it showed Python as it's name not the name I adde to it, I can not target it with pid, because it is changing. What can I do?

[I know what difference is Processes and Threads but do not know which one is better in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044580/multiprocessing-vs-threading-python). When I tried with threads, but `enumarate()` did not show specific threat and when I added to same code, what created it "Thread-1" showed not the name I added.

Comment: You can keep the spawned thread in the dictionary, with the name as a key. Then you will always have easy access to the specific thread.

Comment: Let me see if I understood you correctly - you want to run multiple sub-processes in one Python process, and you want to stop individual sub-processes in that process from a completely separate Python process?